# [S1000]ERROR: syntax error at or near "create" at character 29;

Tags: linux, postgresql, isql

While using ISQL in linux for POSTGRES, I am able to make a connection to the database and execute select/update/insert/delete statements on tables.

But I am unable to execute create/drop/grant statements. I am getting error as below,

1.CREATE

```
SQL> create table shop (item1 integer);
[S1000]ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create" at character 29;
Error while executing the query
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
SQL> create table shop (item1 int);
[S1000]ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create" at character 29;
Error while executing the query
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
```

2.DROP

```
SQL> drop table persons2;
[S1000]ERROR:  syntax error at or near "drop" at character 29;
Error while executing the query
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
```

3.SELECT

```
SQL> select * from persons2;

| personid   | pname                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------- 
------------+
| 1          | test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 2          | test2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
| 3          | test3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
| 4          | test4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
SQLRowCount returns 4
4 rows fetched
```

Grant does not work as well. Is this a permission issue? Please find my permissions below

```
SQL> SELECT rolname, rolsuper, rolcreaterole FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname 
= 'me';
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| rolname   | rolsuper| rolcreaterole|
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| me        | 1       | 0            |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

Also I am unable to find any documents for ISQL to check how to find the roles, permissions of a user etc.

I am able to execute all the above statements using PSQL in linux though.

```
psqltest=# create table shop(item1 int);

CREATE TABLE
```